# Bumping anchor to 0.25.0 leads to Access Violation errors

Tags: anchor, rust, anchor-client, upgrade, version

when I try to upgrade anchor to `0.25.0` from `0.24.2` my instructions now return

`Program returned error: Access violation in stack frame 5 at address 0x200005e10 of size 8 by instruction #40036`

Wondering why that is? Checked the breaking changes and none of them should be relevant

Comment: You can narrow this down further to find the root cause: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/163/153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think this was my issue:

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2070

I built with the version of anchor-lang and anchor-spl proposed in the pull request by the issue author and that worked locally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the program endpoint you are calling is blowing the allocated amount of stack memory available ([4Kb](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/overview#memory-map))

There might have been changes to Anchor between the two version that increased the size of some macro-generated variables, bringing the total over the limit.

A way to address that generally involves `Box`-ing some variables/accounts to allocate to the heap instead of the stack. For instance, [this account](https://github.com/armaniferrante/auction-house/blob/9b0c81e5972f2466d47c20f705fc5fd1ca16476c/programs/auction-house/src/lib.rs#L1485) was boxed for that reason, when bumping Anchor back then.